# Why does the vertical position of these elements change so much?

Tags: html, css

It's things like this that make me feel like such a noob.

http://codepen.io/eighteyes/pen/cgLIu[image: bizarre vertical behavior]

i don't have any rationale in my head for why the elements are positioned vertically the way they are. yes  the css is a little janky, in how so many things are assigned the same height and position. but the results are bizarre. especially the textNodes...

HTML

```
wtf is up
<p>a</p>

<br>

this is low
<p></p>

  <br>
<br>

<div>
  <p>s</p>
  <span>Down Here</span>
  <button>^</button>
  <button></button>
  <button>_</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Why is this normal?"/>
      <button class="submit">And This</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div, button, input, span, p {height: 50px; border:1px solid #999;}
button, input, span, p { display:inline-block; }
span {background-color: red }
p {background-color: blue; height:60px}
```

i'm sure it has something to do with the browser base styles, i just don't know how to override / control it, is the problem. i want everything to behave like the empty button, in my div, `no questions asked`.

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: text baselines. learn to hate them.

Comment: "i want everything to behave like the empty button". The behaviour of the empty button is not consistent cross-browser, and it's probably impossible to make other elements replicate the Firefox behaviour, because I think it depends on the setting of an anonymous box which is not directly controllable in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

With your inline-block you should really declare a vertical-align of something.

```
button, input, span, p { 
    display:inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Otherwise all those use slightly different alignment settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try frist doing some reset of the CSS (every browser has his own native rules for the elements), then you need to set vertical alignment.

you can do something like this

```
*{margin:0; padding: 0}
```

This is not the best way to reset your styles but it works
Learn more about CSS RESET

```
http://www.cssreset.com/which-css-reset-should-i-use/
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/ppollono/pen/xnqlc)